# maven deploy test.jar to nexus via command line

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-deploy-plugin

I am using below command for uploading the old artifacts to new nexus as they cannot be rebuild.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file 
  --settings=~/.m2/settings_att_nexus.xml 
  -DgroupId=com.org 
  -Dsources=someone-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar 
  -Djavadoc=someone-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar 
  -Dtestjar=someone-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
  -DpomFile=someone-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT.pom 
  -DartifactId=someone 
  -Dversion=3.3.1-SNAPSHOT 
  -DgeneratePom=false -Dpackaging=jar 
  -DrepositoryId=snapshots 
  -Durl=http://someurl:8076/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots 
  -Dfile=someone-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

All required jars are uploaded successfully but **someone-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar** doesn't go into nexus which is passed as an argument to above command with below tag:

```
-Dtestjar=someone-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
```

Can someone tell what is correct tag to maven deploy to uplaod test.jar in one go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

whats about your settings.xml? you should have something like this:

```
            [...]
            <repository>
                <id>Snapshot</id>
                <url>http://192.168.28.35/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
            [...]
```

edit:

as I saw, the "testjar" is not existing in the deploy plugin. you can try this:

```
[...]
     -Dfiles=someone-3.3.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
     -Dtypes=jar
     -Dclassifiers=tests
[...]
```

Comment: there is no issue with settings.xml